# String Concat Vs Substring in Queries - Which has better performance?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, say table1 and table2 with sample data as below:

```
Table1 (User_id)
--------------------
    X1011
    X1175
    X1234

Table2 (User_id)
-----------------    
    1011
    1175
    1234
```

I need to write a query with a where condition, where I would compare these two values. Which of the following in general, would be better/advisable and why?

```
1. WHERE TABLE1.USER_ID = 'X' || TABLE2.USER_ID;

2. WHERE TABLE1.USER_ID = CONCAT ('X', TABLE2.USER_ID);

3. WHERE SUBSTR(TABLE1.USER_ID,2) = TABLE2.USER_ID;
```

Both columns are indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to answer a performance question is to test the different options on your data and on your system.

I wouldn't expect the performance of these to be radically different, except for the impact on the execution plan.  When you wrap a column in a function, then that affects the execution plan.  First it affects the use of indexes and second it affects the statistics used for choosing various underlying algorithms.  The actual execution of functions would (in all likelihood) have minimal impact.

I would suggest that you create a functional index.  For instance, using the third example:

```
create index idx_table1_f1 on table1(substr(user_id, 2));
```

Or for the second example:

```
create index idx_table2_f1 on table2(CONCAT('X', TABLE2.USER_ID));
```

Apart from fixing your data structure so the keys really are the same thing, this is probably the best step you can take to improve performance.

Comment: Can I create a functional index on table 2? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Examples 1 and 2 are equivalent. Choosing between 1 and 3 depends on what table is leading and what is lead in the join (if you are going to use join). Anyway giving the actual query you are going to use and, at least, the row counts for these tables will help to give you the answer.

And, well, you may try to use 1 and 3 together. So the optimizer could change the best access path according to the statistics.